# How to set UnitSystem permanently

Tags: units, system-variables, configuration

I would like to set the system of units ([`$UnitSystem`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$UnitSystem.html)) permanently to `"Metric"`.

I know that I can do

```
$UnitSystem = "Metric"
```

Or use the option `UnitSystem -> "Metric"`, but I would like that change to be permanent and be there when the next session is started.

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, UnitSystem -> "Metric"]
```

Does not solve the problem (and by the way now I have a meaningless permanent option for `$FrontEnd` that I don't know how to remove).

Comment: Why not put that in `init.m`?

Comment: Why go against the flow - imperial units are bound to make a comeback.  This metric thing is just a fad :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm on "10.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 4, 2014)", but the action should not differ for other systems substantially. Nevertheless, a backup is indicated with every system manipulation.

Find the default unit system:

```
$UnitSystem
```

> Imperial

The base directory in which user-specific files are placed:

```
$UserBaseDirectory
```

> ```
> /Users/xxxx/Library/Mathematica
> ```

And the files within this Directory:

```
FileNames["*", "/Users/xxxx/Library/Mathematica"] // Column
```

> ```
> {
>  {"/Users/xxxx/Library/Mathematica/ApplicationData"},
>  {"/Users/xxxx/Library/Mathematica/Applications"},
>  {"/Users/xxxx/Library/Mathematica/Autoload"},
>  {"/Users/xxxx/Library/Mathematica/FrontEnd"},
>  {"/Users/xxxx/Library/Mathematica/Kernel"},
>  {"/Users/xxxx/Library/Mathematica/Licensing"},
>  {"/Users/xxxx/Library/Mathematica/Logs"},
>  {"/Users/xxxx/Library/Mathematica/Paclets"},
>  {"/Users/xxxx/Library/Mathematica/SystemFiles"}
> }
> ```

Find all `init.m`withiun this Directory:

```
initFiles = FileNames["init.m", $UserBaseDirectory, Infinity]
```

> ```
> {"/Users/xxxx/Library/Mathematica/Applications/WSMLink/Kernel/init.\
> m", "/Users/xxxx/Library/Mathematica/FrontEnd/init.m", \
> "/Users/xxxx/Library/Mathematica/Kernel/init.m"}
> ```

Your **User Mathematica initialization file**

```
FilePrint@Last@initFiles
```

Will show in the same *.nb the following:

> ```
> (** User Mathematica initialization file **)
>
> $UnitSystem = "Metric"
> ```

What to do:

1. Locate your Kernel/init.m file
2. Open the init.m file with a text editor
3. Add statement an save the file

Restart MMA and check.