# Change units in PlanetData["Earth", "Diameter"] from miles to km

Tags: curated-data, units, entity, configuration

When I enter

```
AstronomicalData["Earth", "Radius"]
```

I get `Quantity[6.3674447*10^6, "Meters"]`

I would have preferred kilometers, but I can live with meters.

Now there is a newfangled `PlanetData` command which gives the radius of the Earth in **miles**.

I know I can convert

```
UnitConvert[PlanetData["Earth", "Radius"], "SI"]
   Quantity[6371.008, "Kilometers"]
```

But that is just silly!  Is there a way to tell *Mathematica* to always use SI when applicable?

Comment: What does `$UnitSystem` return? I get "Metric", and radius in meters (v11.0, Ubuntu 16.04).

Comment: May be related: [117916](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/117916/how-to-set-unitsystem-permanently). Something I don't get is why does "SI" returns kilometers. The SI unit for lengths in meter, not km?!

Comment: @anderstood. That's because to get true SI base units, you need to leave the target units argument blank, which causes MMA to default to "SIBase":  UnitConvert[PlanetData["Earth", "Radius"]]  or, equivalently, 
UnitConvert[PlanetData["Earth", "Radius"], "SIBase"]   When you instead specify "SI", MMA selects the "common" metric unit that gives a numeric value closest to 1 ("common" in this case means km, rather than Mm, even though Mm would give a qty closer to 1).   As another example, compare:  UnitConvert[Quantity[.0001, "Inches"]] to 
UnitConvert[Quantity[.0001, "Inches"], "SI"]

Comment: I'll add that km is an accepted SI unit for length (since prefixes are allowed in SI), it's just not the *base* unit, which is meters.

Comment: @Anderstood $UnitSystem on V10.x MicroS*** returns *Imperial*.  As for getting friendly SI units.  I'm good with that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `UnitSystem` option of `EntityProperty`,

```
EntityValue[Entity["Planet", "Earth"],
 EntityProperty[
  "Planet",
  "Radius",
  UnitSystem -> "Metric"
  ]
 ]
(* Quantity[6371.008, "Kilometers"] *)
```

Why am I talking about `EntityValue` when you asked about `PlanetData`?  Because `PlanetData` calls `EntityValue` under the hood (as do all newer `XXXData` functions).

If you still want to use the `PlanetData` function, you can do the following,

```
SetOptions[
 EntityProperty,
 UnitSystem -> "Metric"
 ]
(* {UnitSystem -> "Metric"} *)

PlanetData[
 "Earth",
 "Radius"
 ]
(* Quantity[6371.008, "Kilometers"] *)
```

If you would like this option to be persistent across kernel sessions, you can add the `SetOptions` line above in your `init.m` file, whose location is described [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/63741/9490).