# Converting Units

Tags: curated-data, units, astronomy

I'm using MMA 12.2. Trying to put together some astronomy pages, but the output of the command below is in miles. I would rather have it in SI units instead.

On my system evaluating `$UnitSystem` returns `Imperial`.

Can I (or even should I) change the units for the whole Notebook, or even all of MMA?

[image: output of command above]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change units in PlanetData\["Earth", "Diameter"\] from miles to km](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/163844/change-units-in-planetdataearth-diameter-from-miles-to-km). You may also be interested in [How to set UnitSystem permanently](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/117916/27951).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to change `$UnitSystem` globally

```
Block[{$UnitSystem = "Metric"}, PlanetData[PlanetData[], "Radius", "EntityAssociation"]]
```

Comment: Does that work to return km units? I still get miles.

Comment: @MarcoB Strange, I get `km` even though `$UnitSystem` is `Imperial` outside the `Block`.

Comment: MarcoB --- It changes to "km" for me.

Comment: Rohit.....That's beautiful!....it's great, it's easy, and it works, and I'm gonna use it. I'll also have to try and understand WHY it works. I've been messing around with this for 2 weeks, and I greatly appreciate this! Thank you!

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi --- for a quantity (same project same type command you helped with before, MMA gives Density data for these planets in "g/cm^3"....is there a way to force this to be "kg/m^3"?   ugh....MMA does NOT manage units very gracefully.

Comment: @fiz That will have to be done explicitly since for Metric/SI the units are g/cm^3. One way `PlanetData[PlanetData[], "Density", "EntityAssociation"] // Map[UnitConvert[#, "Kilograms"/"Meters"^3] &]`

Comment: @fiz I see that you asked this in a [new question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/237701/58370). The responses there are better than what I suggested above.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can change it:

```
$UnitSystem = "Metric"
```

If you want to make the change permanent, you can change the init.m file or just evaluate the command above whenever you run Mathematica.

Also, you can use the UnitConvert function:

```
PlanetData[PlanetData[], "Radius", "EntityAssociation"] //
Map[UnitConvert[#, Quantity[1, "AstronomicalUnit"]] &]


<|Mercury -> 0.00001631 au, Venus -> 0.00004045 au, Earth -> 0.000042587563 au, Mars -> 0.000022658 au, Jupiter -> 0.0004675 au, Saturn -> 0.00038971 au, Uranus -> 0.0001695 au, Neptune -> 0.0001646 au|>
```

Comment: Does the global change work to return km units? I still get miles.

Comment: Also `UnitConvert[PlanetData[PlanetData[], "Radius", "EntityAssociation"], "AstronomicalUnit"]` works just as well.