# Units Question for PlanetData[..]

Tags: curated-data, units, astronomy

I asked a similar question yesterday, which was answered splendidly, but I missed adding a detail.

Attached is a command, its output, and the issue I have now. This outputs g/cm^3, but I'd rather have the units in kg/m^3.

I guess I don't know how to handle the command which outputs all the data at once. How can the units be changed for this kind of output?

Thank you (again)[image]

Comment: For future reference, please add your code as text, and not as pictures, so we don't have to retype it ourselves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UnitConvert[
 PlanetData[PlanetData[], "Density", "EntityAssociation"],
 "Kilograms"/"Meters"^3
]
```

Of course I am sure you are aware that the two units result in the same numerical results, i.e. 1 g/cm^3 = 1 kg/m^3.

Comment: Pipped me by 31 seconds :)

Comment: @CarlLange Great minds, and all that... :-)

Comment: @MarcoB --- Terrific.....I don't even understand the answer I got yesterday, but I will...and now THIS one. It's simple, and easy. I appreciate it! I hope I can understand and do this on my own.

Comment: Also, `UnitConvert[PlanetData[PlanetData[], "Density", "EntityAssociation"], "SIBase"]`